# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para habilitar código entre llaves dentro de un comentario?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vscode

Es decir, estoy ejecutando la siguiente línea de código:

```javascript
var response = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:5000/users?email=${this.state.email}&password=${this.state.password}",
      { method: "GET" }
    );
```

Lo importante aquí son el símbolo del dolar y las llaves; es decir:
cuando escribo `${this.state.email}` me los toma como si fuese un comentario completo pegado a la url que acabo de proporcionar.

Mi pregunta es cómo hago para habilitar este trozo de codigo (`${this.state.email}` y el de la contraseña tambien: `${this.state.password}`) para que pueda tomar en cuenta esos estados de ese componente y no los tome en cuenta como un simple comentario, es en VS code.

Post-data: no sé si es que tengo que habilitar algo en VS code o es otra cosa.

Comment: No entiendo lo que preguntas, pero por el código que pones (deberías formatearlo correctamente) necesitas consultar la sintaxis de ECMAScript 6 https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
Cambia las comillas de la cadena: ``"http://localhost:5000/users?email=${this.state.email}&password=${this.state.password}"`` por comilla simple invertida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta te dejo un ejemplo de como podrías hacer lo que pides:

```js
var id = 45;
var name = "carlos";
var apellido = "muñoz";
var edad = 45;

var info = `id: ${id}, nombre: ${name}, apellido: ${apellido}, edad: ${edad}`;

console.log(info);
```

Para usar las `plantillas literales (plantillas de cadena)` se debe de usar  las comillas (tildes) invertidas ``

Espero haberte ayudado :)

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tenia era con las comillas, simplemente estaba usando "", cuando debía usar ´´, eso fue todo lo que tuve que hacer

Comment: Si el error era tipográfico borra la pregunta. Si las comillas que has usado son las invertidas tal como te decian en los comentarios, puedes [edit] esta respuesta y ponerlas escapándolas con una barra invertida, es decir \\` \\`